# Отправка формы на другой сайт

Tags: php, mysql

Здраствуйте, нужно с формы сайта 1 отправить данные в форму сайта 2 где есть вход в аккаунт( делаю для того, что если на моем сайте 2 есть такой уже пользователь, тогда на 1 пропускало без проблем), подключать базу данных и проверять через неё не хочу, нужно именно так.

После ввода данных и отправке с сайта 1 нужно или перенаправление на сайт 2 уже со входом( если такой аккаунт уже есть) или вывод информации "Пользователь не зарегистрирован" или "Пользователь установил двухфакторную...", я сделал еще, чтобы на почту приходили рандомные числа, которые он должен ввести в поле двухфакторной.

Можно ли это сделать и как, если не трудно напишите пример :)

p.s Форма с сайта 1 отправляется сейчас через action='сайт2.php/login.php', но данные улетают в базу, а меня просто перекидывает в форму входа :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Отправить пост запрос на сайт `сайт.php/login.php`, далее curl отправляешь пост запрос на `сайт2.php/login.php`, в ответ получаешь токен **Bearer** , после чего просто делаешь ридерект на `сайт2.php?auth={token}` и по токену делаешь авторизацию на `сайт2.php`.
2. чтоб реализовать способ как у тебя, можно сделать на сайте два редирект пользователя в файле login.php на адрес из переменной `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, самый быстрый вариант.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, можете подробнее описать способ №1, какой-то пример как это должно работать

Comment: @MaksymVintoniak смотрите в сторону bearer авторизации